# Detecting total sales changes from a portion of the data

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, sample

On a month to month basis, I usually see around 20% of Product A's total orders and I do not see 80% of Product A's total orders. In January, I observe that Product A has 5 orders(which is let's say around 20% of total orders, so total orders for product A is around 25 orders in Jan). In February, I observe that Product A has 10 orders. After observing the data, I make the statement that Product A's orders went up 100% from Jan to Feb.

With what accuracy can I tell that I see 20% of total orders so that I can make an assertion that monthly percent changes of my sample resemble the percent changes of the population of total orders?

Comment: I think the question is really with what accuracy I can tell that I see 0.2 of total orders. Otherwise, if you are sure you get exactly 0.2, you are sure the order volume has grown 100%. Is this right? If so, can you make an estimate of the accuracy of 0.2?

Comment: @AlexeyBurnakov thank you for the comment. You are right. I will make the changes.